# Label and Textfield won't appear

Tags: java, user-interface

So, we have a group project and we need to make a food ordering system with login and register and I'm tasked with the login layout. I used what I did on my other GUI's but I don't know why it doesn't work here. The userL and the textfield won't show. The imageIcon and it's label "LOGIN" does appear, however.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class OOPproject implements ActionListener{
    //declarations
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField userTF, passwordTF;
    JLabel loginL, userL, passwordL, createL;
    JButton loginB; 
    //layout
    OOPproject(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("11.png");
        loginL = new JLabel("L O G I N");
        loginL.setIcon(image);
        loginL.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        loginL.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        loginL.setForeground(new Color(0,191,255));
        loginL.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,35));
        loginL.setIconTextGap(5); 
        loginL.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        loginL.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        loginL.setBounds(-8, -110, 400, 400);
        frame.add(loginL);
        userL = new JLabel("Username");
        userL.setBounds(-16, -200, 12, 12);
        userL.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        userL.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        userL.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,12));
        userL.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.add(userL);
        userTF = new JTextField();
        userTF.setBackground(Color.white);
        userTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        frame.add(userTF);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OOPproject proj = new OOPproject();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to define a layout, otherwise how could the program know how to draw your stuff https://www.google.com/amp/s/javatutorial.net/java-swing-jframe-layouts/amp

Comment: You are setting negative `x` and `y` in the bounds for `userL`. That means `userL` will be placed outside of its container. So why do you think it should be visible? Also you have not set bounds for `userTF`. When you use null layout manager, you must set bounds for every component in your GUI. Note that _Swing_ has layout managers that exist to help you. Refer to [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).